# Iterating Over a Hash Object in Stylus

Tags: stylus

I have a made a hash object of colors in stylus - like this (these are bootstrap 4 colors):

```
colors: {
  white:  #fff,
  light: #f8f9fa,
  black:  #000,
  dark: #212529,
  grey: {
    base: #adb5bd,
    light: #ced4da,
    lighter: #dee2e6,
    lightest: #e9ecef,
    dark: #868e96,
    darker: #495057,
    darkest: #343a40,
  },
  blue:    #007bff,
  indigo:  #6610f2,
  purple:  #6f42c1,
  pink:    #e83e8c,
  red:     #dc3545,
  orange:  #fd7e14,
  yellow:  #ffc107,
  green:   #28a745,
  teal:    #20c997,
  cyan:    #17a2b8
}
```

What I would like to do is iterate over this list and create light and dark variations -- something like this:

```
for color in colors
    dark-{color} = darken({color}, 10%)
```

My end goal is to have a list of variables that I can use -- like this:  `dark-green`, `light-purple`, etc.

Or, alternatively, like this:  `colors.dark-green`, `colors.light-purple`, etc.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code like this,

```
colors: {
  white:  #fff,
  light: #f8f9fa,
  black:  #000,
  dark: #212529,
  blue:    #007bff,
  indigo:  #6610f2,
  purple:  #6f42c1,
  pink:    #e83e8c,
  red:     #dc3545,
  orange:  #fd7e14,
  yellow:  #ffc107,
  green:   #28a745,
  teal:    #20c997,
  cyan:    #17a2b8
}

for name, attr in colors
    dark-{name} = darken({attr}, 10%)
```

The name is `Key`, and `Attr` is value